# Expected behaviour when cmd_vel == 0

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just finished writing a hardware interface for my custom robot. It finally performs as hoped, but I'm not sure what `cmd_vel` == 0 m/s should actually cause. Does it mean:

1. Stop powering the robot's wheels, allowing it to coast downhill (i.e. robot is not powered)
2. Hold the robot still, as if it were being actively braked (i.e. robot velocity = 0 m/s)

Maybe it's just personal preference, but I am very interested in hearing what the ROS official convention is.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332587/expected-behaviour-when-cmd_vel-==-0/) by [georgeknowlden](https://answers.ros.org/users/45507/georgeknowlden/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-09-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pasindu_sandima](https://answers.ros.org/users/64362/pasindu_sandima/) on 2020-11-30**:
Hi, I have the same question. I used the diff drive controller in my robot using velocity joint interface. When I place the robot on a ramp and apply 0 `cmd_vel` , it coasts down the ramp. But I want to achieve the other behavior which it brakes it self so it won't coasts down. Any help on how to achieve that?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-12-01**:
Please do not post follow-up questions as answer to already answered questions.

Your question will have very low visibility.

I'd suggest to post a new question, clearly describing your desired behaviour and referring to this one.

---

Edit: seems you already did: #q366698.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For all robots I've worked with, wrote my own hw interfaces for or have used hw interfaces of others with, `cmd_vel` was always used to dictate the *state* in which the system should be (ie: messages encode the desired state or set point). For those robots a command of 0 m/s meant: motors powered, but not rotating.

This has made sense to me, as by convention `cmd_vel` carries setpoints in the form of [geometry_msgs/Twist](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html), which contains the following comment:

> This expresses velocity in free space broken into its linear and angular parts.

So, `Twist`s sent to a mobile base platform encode a body relative set of linear and angular velocities. These are then typically mapped onto joint space velocities for wheels in case of a wheeled mobile base such that 'the robot' (or mobile base) attains the desired attitude.

Following this, a `Twist` carrying only zeroes would encode for a 0 m/s linear and 0 rad/s angular state in the body local reference frame, or in other words: a non-moving robot.

Your other option (unpowered or backdrivable actuators) would lead to a non-zero state in case of "coast[ing] downhill" (as the encoders, which will probably be present to support velocity control, will register a non-zero displacement). That would lead to a velocity error, which a controller would probably try to rectify (by breaking or applying a corrective velocity).

---

Edit: I don't believe there is a REP that documents or standardises this particular aspect (as in: in a robot-agnostic manner), but there is [REP 119: Specification for TurtleBot Compatible Platforms](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0119.html), which in the section called [TurtleBot Node Core API](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0119.html#turtlebot-node-core-api) writes:

> Subscribed Topics
>
> - cmd_vel (`geometry_msgs/Twist`)
>
>   The desired velocity of the robot. The type of this message is determined by the drive_mode parameter. Default is `geometry_msgs/Twist`.

which seems to confirm my experience and intuition.

As almost all use of `cmd_vel` seems to follow this convention (as authors of early nodes looked to existing implementations to match their own against, and TurtleBot and PR2 were the most prominent ones), I believe only your second alternative would be the correct one.

---

Edit 2: there is also [REP 147: A Standard interface for Aerial Vehicles](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0147.html), which doesn't directly deal with `cmd_vel` or its semantics, but discusses something similar in the [Rate Interface](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0147.html#rate-interface) section:

> The command is a body relative set of accelerations in linear and angular space.

Note that this talks about 'accelerations', but the idea and use is similar to `cmd_vel` and velocities for wheeled robots.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgeknowlden](https://answers.ros.org/users/45507/georgeknowlden/) on 2019-09-09**:
Thank you for such a detailed response. This is exactly the information I was looking for, and it makes perfect sense.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-09**:
I believe that if you'd actually want to achieve something like backdrivability, *stopping* any active controller could be used achieve that (in combination with some support in your `hardware_interface`).

You can stop and start controllers with `ros_control` by calling the appropriate service on your instance of the `ControllerManager`.

A combination of `prepareSwitch(..)` and `doSwitch(..)` in your `hardware_interface` could probably be used to determine whether there is *any* active controller, and when there isn't, you could enable some special mode in your hardware that allows for coasting or backdrivability.